# FontAwesome Upgrade from 4 to 5 (Tumblr)

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I am having some trouble upgrading my FontAwesome from 4 to 5. I am using a **Tumblr theme** that had 4, and the icons I want to use are now in 5. I've updated the .css link, I've changed all the font-family instances and I have tried to change the class from "`fa fa-`" to "`fas fa-`" and had zero luck. Half of my icons are showing on my page, and the other half are not.

Help??

Comment: It won't let me add the full theme. It can be found at [link] (https://pastebin.com/NrHdjaZy)

Comment: I am pretty sure you will find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8620333+%5Bfont-awesome-5%5D

Comment: Looking at this link I didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In FontAwesome 5, they have new icon class names.

eg:- `bitbucket-square` is now  `bitbucket`

You have to find them and replace all your icon classes manually.

You can find new class names from [here.](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#name-changes)

I think you can find clear instructions from there [page](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4).

Answer (score 0):

In fontAwesome 5, there are some extra class beginnings beside fas

Like this:

[image]

> **NOTE:** If some icons are shoving and others come as a question mark that means class calling is wrong but your upgrade is successfully
>   done.